# how to url calling return from list function with retrofit

Tags: java, android, list, android-studio, retrofit

i tried to return list from the url that i get with retrofit. it works and i get the data but it wont return.

this is my code

```
public List<MovieResponse> loadCourses() {
    ArrayList<MovieResponse> list = new ArrayList<>();

    ApiServices apiService =
            NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient().create(ApiServices.class);

    Call<MovieResult> call = apiService.getMovies();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MovieResult> call, Response<MovieResult> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                ArrayList<MovieResponse> movies = new ArrayList<>();
                movies = response.body().getResults();
                Log.d("",""+movies);
                list.addAll(movies);
                Log.d("",""+list);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResult> call, Throwable t) {
            // Log error here since request failed
            Log.e("error", t.toString());
        }
    });
     return list;
}
```

when i print list inside `onResponse` it works and there are the data. but when i return it or trying to print list outside `onResponse` for example below `ArrayList<MovieResponse> list = new ArrayList<>();` it not show the data.

please help what is actually wrong with it. i really appreciate it.

Comment: It is most probably because of `callback`. It is `asynchronous` in nature. so your list is not updated by the time you are displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are making asynchronous call which is being handled by a separate thread. So after call.enqueue(), the main thread directly jumps to return statement without waiting for API response, that's why you are getting empty list.

Assuming your API takes 1 sec to respond,
just for an experiment, you can try adding a sleep() for 3 sec right before your return statement, it should return all the movies.

If you must return from the method then go for retrofit synchronous call.

To make a sync call create a new thread in main thread and make call from there, it is not allowed to make network call from main thread because it blocks the thread.

Comment: i tried sync code like this example https://howtodoinjava.com/retrofit2/retrofit-sync-async-calls/ but i got this error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
`

Comment: yes in main thread network call is not allowed because it blocks the thread until api response. So try to create a new thread yourself in your main thread and make the sync call from this thread. you can also use AsyncTask class

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to define your `movies` list directly inside activity or fragment(in other words, a field member of the class).

It's not a good idea to return data from an asynchronous method.
Change the return type of the `loadCourses` method to `void` and instantiate the filed `movies` inside `onResponse()`.

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   private ArrayList<MovieResponse> movies = new ArrayList<>();

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_some);
   }

   public void loadCourses() {
       ApiServices apiService =
               NetworkClient.getRetrofitClient().create(ApiServices.class);

       Call<MovieResult> call = apiService.getMovies();
       call.enqueue(new Callback<MovieResult>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<MovieResult> call, Response<MovieResult> response) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                movies = response.body().getResults();
                ...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MovieResult> call, Throwable t) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: it cannot be declare becouse it wants to be declare like this `final ArrayList<MovieResponse>[] movies = new ArrayList[]{new ArrayList<>()};` but the data still empty when i breakpoint in return. but when i break point inside onResponse the data exist on `list`